# Can WebView do like browser?

Tags: java, android

I have a question bothering me for these few days, I want to implement browser-like WebView, which has add/close tab and open multiple websites. But after I searched through many forums and documentation still couldn't find any solution for this, wondering can WebView do exactly what phone browser can do?

Comment: yes.u can. Android browser is also webview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answered by the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview).

> ## Building web apps in WebView
>
> If you want to deliver a web application (or just a web page) as a part of a client application, you can do it using `WebView`. The `WebView` class is an extension of Android's `View` class that allows you to display web pages as a part of your activity layout. **It does not include any features of a fully developed web browser, such as navigation controls or an address bar.** All that `WebView` does, by default, is show a web page.

So the answer to your question is No.  The `WebView` class cannot do exactly what a phone browser can do.

This does not stop you from implementing missing browser features for yourself ... starting with `WebView`. However, the [javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) for `WebView` states this:

> **In most cases, we recommend using a standard web browser**, like Chrome, to deliver content to the user. To learn more about web browsers, read the guide on [invoking a browser with an intent](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Browser).
>
> *And more ...*